# Ionic CLI V4 Looks like @ionic/v1-toolkit isn't installed in this project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-cli, ionic4

After updating Ionic CLI to 4, every command I try to run does not working.

For example:

```
Ionic serve,
ionic cordova build android
ionic cordova run android
ionic cordova build ios
...
```

I receive such errors:

```
Looks like @ionic/v1-toolkit isn't installed in this project.
```

Then I try to install the package as they ask:

```
? Install @ionic/v1-toolkit? Yes
> npm i -D -E @ionic/v1-toolkit
```

But I get the following error in return:

```
npm WARN rsdemo.razwebs.co.il@1.1.1 No repository field.
npm WARN rsdemo.razwebs.co.il@1.1.1 No license field.

npm ERR! Cannot read property '0' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/razbuchnik/.npm/_logs/2018-08-17T05_49_32_425Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

        npm i -D -E @ionic/v1-toolkit exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more 
        information.
net.js:705
    throw new errors.TypeError('ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE',
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type object
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:705:11)
    at process.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic:9:63)
    at process.emit (events.js:159:13)
    at emitPendingUnhandledRejections (internal/process/promises.js:94:22)
    at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:124:9)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete `node_modules` directory and `npm i` again